# (WindowsError 183) cv2.imread/write how to make these function in different locations for the running script

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am running my script from the dir path C:\Automation\OCR\images. The PNG that we are reading in is also in that path. The output path is: C:\Automation\OCR\Drop. What happens is that I get an error in my shell saying WindowsError: [Error 183] Cannot create a file when that file already exists: 'C:\Automation\OCR\Drop' I want to be able to have the script isolated, read a PNG file from a particular folder, then output the preprocessed PNG in a different folder.

Pics below.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2P38.jpg

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import math
import os
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from cycler import cycler
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

# Read PNG
dirname = 'C:\Automation\OCR\Drop'
os.mkdir(dirname)
img = cv2.imread('teleCapture.png', 0)

def bilateral_adaptive_threshold(img, ksize=20, C=0, mode='floor', true_value=255, false_value=0):
mask = np.full(img.shape, false_value, dtype=np.uint8)

kernel_l = np.array([[1] * (ksize) + [-ksize]], dtype=np.int16)
kernel_r = np.array([[-ksize] + [1] * (ksize)], dtype=np.int16)
kernel_u = np.array([[1]] * (ksize) + [[-ksize]], dtype=np.int16)
kernel_d = np.array([[-ksize]] + [[1]] * (ksize), dtype=np.int16)

if mode == 'floor':
    delta = C * ksize
elif mode == 'ceil':
    delta = -C * ksize
else: raise ValueError("Unexpected mode value. Expected value is 'floor' or 'ceil'.")

left_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_l, anchor=(ksize,0), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
right_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_r, anchor=(0,0), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
up_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_u, anchor=(0,ksize), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)
down_thresh = cv2.filter2D(img, cv2.CV_16S, kernel_d, anchor=(0,0), delta=delta, borderType=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

if mode == 'floor':
    mask[((0 > left_thresh) & (0 > right_thresh)) | ((0 > up_thresh) & (0 > down_thresh))] = true_value
elif mode == 'ceil':
    mask[((0 < left_thresh) & (0 < right_thresh)) | ((0 < up_thresh) & (0 < down_thresh))] = true_value
return mask

# Write modified PNG to the path
os.chdir(dirname)
cv2.imwrite('enhancedThresholdTeleCapture.png', img)
```

Comment: Can you reword your question? I can't understand what you are asking

Comment: I have no idea what you want, but how is this line `img = cv2.imwrite('enhancedThresholdTeleCapture.png',0)`supposed to save an image if you don't provide the function with an input image? that function also does not return an image so I guess you have never read the OpenCV documentation befor using those functions...

Comment: @Milk I have edited this post heavily.

Comment: @Piglet I have edited the post with clarification

Comment: Instead of making and switching directories through `os` why don't you just...specify the full paths of the locations? This is not the type of script `os.chdir` is really meant for...literally just do `cv2.imwrite(directory+'filename.png', img)`. Also this is a completely different question from what you originally posted. You should not do that; you should have accepted the answer that responded to the original question and opened a new question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
img = cv2.imwrite('enhancedThresholdTeleCapture.png',0)
```

should instead be

```
cv2.imwrite('enhancedThresholdTeleCapture.png', img)
```

If you're getting unexpected behavior, be sure to search the OpenCV docs so you know the proper way to call functions and so that you can get the expected return value. For example, the [docs for `cv2.imwrite()`](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgcodecs/doc/reading_and_writing_images.html#imwrite) show:

> **Python:** `cv2.imwrite(filename, img[, params]) → retval`
>
> **Parameters:**
>
> - **filename** – Name of the file.
> - **image** – Image to be saved.
> - **params** – ...

Along with a description of the function and what it does. The syntax

```
cv2.imwrite(filename, img[, params]) → retval
```

tells us everything we need to know to call the function. The function has two *required* arguments, `filename` and `img`. The last argument shown, `params`, is *optional* (and is only used for special options for certain filetypes). The brackets inside the list signify that it's optional. Then the arrow `→` shows the return value. If there is no return value for the function, it is simply `None`. In this case, there is a return value; named `retval` for "return value", so it's not very descriptive. Most unnamed return values are unimportant or are used for debugging purposes; in cases where some action is performed with the file system, it's pretty common for such a return value to be a boolean letting you know whether the action was successfully completed or not.

In the future, you can also run `help(cv2.imwrite)` (or with any other OpenCV function) inside your interpreter and you should be able to get the syntax line shown above so you can at least see how the function should be called.

Comment: I am using img = cv2.imread('C:\Automation\OCR\images\teleCapture.png', 0) to read a PNG file ... after preprocessing this image I will be writing this modified file to a specific directory. (The python script, read file and write file are 3 different locations) here is what I have for writing. cv2.imwrite('C:\Automation\OCR\hey\enhancedThresholdTeleCapture.png', img) When I write the file to this location, the output PNG file is not readable. I will attach photos showing what happens when the output is where script the script is VS a different location. @AlexanderReynolds